# Visual Basic: Concatenate New CSV Into Excel Cell

Tags: vb.net

New to VBA, and I'm missing something simple but have been staring at this for an hour: I want to allow the user to enter another CSV to an existing Excel cell that has some CSVs already. The code below works, but is a bit too over-eager: it repeats the string twice so that if I had 5, 7, 9 before and wanted to add 10 it now says 5, 7, 9, 10, 5, 7, 9, 10 instead of just 5, 7, 9, 10.

What am I missing?

```
Private Sub vbKeyReturnSS(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress

    If e.KeyChar = ChrW(13) Then
        Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
        Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet

        oExcel = New Excel.Application      'Create a new instance of Excel
        oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\QA Controller Test Files\" & SelectController.Text & ".xlsm")
        oSheet = oExcel.Worksheets(1)
        oSheet.Range("B2").Value = oSheet.Range("B2").Value & ", " & TextBox2.Text
        oExcel.Visible = True               'Show it to the user

        oBook = Nothing                     'Disconnect from Excel (let the user take over)
        oExcel = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Code looks legit to me. Why don't debug step by step using F8 and look at the values of `Range("B2")`?

Comment: Something strange is going on: I single-stepped through, and the values in Range are correct right up until the assignment of the old values plus the new, at which point I see the same thing as in my Excel worksheet: two of each entry. Changed the assignment line to 'oSheet.Range("B2").Value = TextBox2.Text', and I STILL get two of whatever I entered into the textbox. Also confirmed the value of TextBox2.Text is correct (i.e., contains just one number).

Comment: Something about converting from text to value?

Comment: Looks like I've got another issue going on, as I just noticed I'm having the same issue with another button-press handler where it is duplicating the user entries.